# importRange and import comments?

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to import comments along with cell values. I am using importRage() for the values. I have also found the following Google Apps Script which is supposed to get the comments:

```
    function importComments(spreadsheetKey,a1NotationReference) {
      return SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheetKey).getRange(a1NotationReference).getComments();
    }
```

Everytime I run it, though, I get a "Missing formal parameter" error.

I have tried running it like this as well with no luck/

```
    function importComments(0AqvTp4ajjRSUdHYyV09QcWtnRFQ2SDUwSTF6OTBKQ0E,Overall!B2:I2) {
      return SpreadsheetApp.openById(0AqvTp4ajjRSUdHYyV09QcWtnRFQ2SDUwSTF6OTBKQ0E).getRange(Overall!B2:I2).getComments();
    };
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I'm not too sure but do they need to be string literals? e.g. `"0AqvTp4ajjRSUdHYyV09QcWtnRFQ2SDUwSTF6OTBKQ0E"` and `"Overall!B2:I2"` and if possible can provide a link to the page where you got this script so we can see the documentation?

Comment: I got the script from [here](https://productforums.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/apps-script/ESGAV9OPEKM)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not calling the function back correctly, the below is what you add to the Google Script manager. This does not need to be changed.

```
function importComments(spreadsheetKey,a1NotationReference) {
      return SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheetKey).getRange(a1NotationReference).getComments();
    }
```

You then call this back in the spreadsheet using the below function. Just type into a cell like a normal spreadsheet equations.

```
=importComments("0AqvTp4ajjRSUdHYyV09QcWtnRFQ2SDUwSTF6OTBKQ0E", "Overall!B2:I2")
```

As Henrique Abreu on the Google forum mentioned, this works very similar to importRange. [Have a look at this page for the usage](http://support.google.com/drive/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=155183) of that as it will help with importComments.

**EDIT** Example of both... ***not tested***

```
function importBoth(spreadsheetKey,a1NotationReference){
   return SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheetKey).getRange(a1NotationReference).getComments();
   return SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheetKey).getRange(a1NotationReference).getValue();
}
```

Comment: So, importRange and importComments can't be used in tandem to import cells with importRange and comment those cells with importComments?

Comment: Probably not, but you could create a second function that calls both of them with the same argument.

Comment: importComments and importBoth return empty cells.

Comment: The linked page is gone. :-(

Comment: How you deal with authorization? My script fails to authorize since it requires permission - `you do not have permission to call Spreadsheet.openById`